# SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest setTransientWebhook

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm looking for a sample code using SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest::setTransientWebhook for Transient VSI. Is there a sample code?

Thanks
Behzad

Answer (score 1):

Try with next requests:

**Method GET**

```
http://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?objectMask=mask[id,transientGuestFlag]&objectFilter={"virtualGuests":{"transientGuestFlag":{"operation": 1}}}
```

Data 1 means true also 0 means false, in this case, we use one with data 1

Choose the VSI id  you want to set and use the following request:

**Method POST**

```
http://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3.1/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/111111/setTransientWebhook
```

**Body**

```
{"parameters":[
       "https://test1.com",
       "testsupport"]
}
```

The 111111 data is the VSI that we chose in the previous request.

**Reference**

https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/#transientGuestFlag
https://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_Guest/setTransientWebhook/

I hope it helps you

Comment: Thanks Daniel for this. I tried to convert your REST/API to a Python version like this:

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Daniel,                                                                       would this be equivalent code in python:                                                    request = client['Virtual_Guest'].createObject({
                                                   'hostname': hostname,
                                                    'domain': domainname,
                                                    'startCpus': cpus,
                                                    'maxMemory': memory,
                                                    'hourlyBillingFlag': 'true',
                                                    'datacenter': {'name': 'tor01'}, 
                                                    'operatingSystemReferenceCode': os_code,
                                                    # 'localDiskFlag': 'false',
                                                    "supplementalCreateObjectOptions": {"flavorKeyName": "C1_1X1X25"},
                                                    'transientGuestFlag': 'true',
                                                    # 'sshKeys': [{"id":201867}]
                                                    "parameters":["https://test1.com","testsupport"].